# How to separate DATE and TIME from DATETIME in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I am storing a `DATETIME` field in a table. Each value looks something like this:

> 2012-09-09 06:57:12

I am using this syntax:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Now my question is, while fetching the data, how can get both date and time ***separately***, using a single MySQL query?

Date like "**2012-09-09**" and time like "**06:57:12**".

Comment: probably you're looking for `DATE_FORMAT` and not `DATE` and `TIME` because it will give you default date if you are looking for time and default time if you are looking for date, see my answer below.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

You can achieve that using **[DATE_FORMAT()](http://davidwalsh.name/format-date-mysql-date_format)** (*click the link for more other formats*)

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(colName, '%Y-%m-%d') DATEONLY, 
       DATE_FORMAT(colName,'%H:%i:%s') TIMEONLY
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/1842)

Comment: Hi, How to get the value?? can i use `echo DATEONLY` for Printing date and `echo TIMEONLY` for printing the time?? Or What??

Comment: @MissRosy yes, you can use their alias (*eg DATEONLY and TIMEONLY*) to get the values you want.

Comment: @MissRosy [click the link for demonstration](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/1853)

Comment: @MissRosy you're welcome. the best thing is you can format it to any form you want.

Comment: Stop using SQLFiddle. Unstable page.

Answer (score 64):

Per the MySQL documentation, the [`DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function will pull the date part of a datetime field, and [`TIME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) for the time portion.

So I would try the following:

```
SELECT DATE(dateTimeField) as Date,
       TIME(dateTimeField) as Time
FROM Table1;
```

Comment: It's nice to know that comparisons on this work as expected, e.g. `SELECT * FROM sales WHERE TIME(sold_at_utc) >= '12:00:00';` - to get sales recorded after noon, regardless of their date.

Answer (score 18):

Try:

```
SELECT DATE(`date_time_field`) AS date_part, TIME(`date_time_field`) AS time_part FROM `your_table`
```

Comment: this will not get the `DATE` and `TIME` only as what the user is asking. It will give the whole date and time with its defaults. [SELL THIS LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/1845)

Comment: it will generate `September, 09 2012 00:00:00-0400` for *DATE* and `January, 01 1970 03:20:38-0500` for *TIME*

Comment: well, as per query it gives 2012-09-09 as date_part and 06:57:12 as time part in mysql

Comment: @Sudhir..Thanks a lot for replying.This is also correct but..using `DATE_FORMAT()` make you more flexible.

Comment: @MissRosy welcome, and yes you should be using a solution that suits the most and is more flexible.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply,
SELECT TIME(column_name), DATE(column_name)

Comment: How about `DATE`?

Answer (score -2):

An easy way would be:

For date:

```
SELECT DATE(datetime_column) as mydate
```

For time:

```
SELECT TIME(datetime_column) as mytime
```

Answer (score -3):

For only date use
`date("Y-m-d");`

and for only time use
`date("H:i:s");`

Comment: hey your giving a php's solution not sql's :)