# What is the best way to store date and time in mysqli database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

What is the best way to store date and time into separate fields in MySQL database.

I will perform following actions in the query :

- sort the tables with date, ASC or DSC
- sort the tables with respect to time,
- select tables by certain conditions such as:

  example query :

  ```
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE starttime > '$starttime AND endtime < $endtime
  ```

lets say

```
$date = "11/12/2016";
$starttime = "09:00 AM";
$endtime = "05:00 PM";
```

what is the best way to store these in correct format?

Comment: Store the date with `datetime` datatype

Comment: You can do this without separating the the two (date and time)

Comment: but what if i have to display only time?  like, start time of meeting?

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337195/how-to-part-date-and-time-from-datetime-in-mysql

Comment: @BilalSardar then you select the datetime and only display the time. how you save it does not define how you present it.

Comment: is this the correct way then >

Answer (score 2):

In our use cases we have to consider time zones, so a complete date is a combination of date,time and timezone.

Since date and time are related I prefer to translate everything to miliseconds since 1.1.1970 in UTC (epoch timestamp) and store these values. The advantage is an absolute time without the need to remember the timezone. Sorting, filtering, finding intersection of appointments is very easy.

However the moment you translate the long value back to a human readable value you need the time zone for which the date was created. So you must keep this data somewhere. In general the timezone is the for one user so all date related to a user have the same timezone.

Comment: timezone is irrelevant to me, i just want good database structure,  so that i can perform any operation in queries