# Date filter on column in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have query that filtered by date, for now it take only the last 24h from the moment I execute it, for doing that I'm using the next code:

```
( DateDiff(HH, vw_public_task.complete_date, getdate()) < 25)
```

There is a way that my date filter will give query results for the last 24h but not depending on my current hour but according to "`day 08:00am`" -- "`day+1 08:00am`" at any time that I execute it?.

For example if I execute my query now I want to see date results from yesterday `08:00am` till today `08:00am`.

Comment: Your code will generate an error in MySQL.  Tag your question correctly.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate yesterday 8am using the formula:

```
-- Yesterday at 8 am.
SELECT
    DATEADD(HOUR, 8, CAST(CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS DATETIME)) AS Yesterday8AM
;
```

[GetDate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188383.aspx) returns the current date.  The innermost [date add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186819.aspx) subtracts one day.  Casting this as a date removes the timestamp.  Casting this back to a DateTime gives yesterday at midnight.  Now we are dealing with a DateTime we can use date add, again, to add 8 hours.

If you are using SQL Server 2012, or above, consider the native function [DATETIME2FROMPARTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213312(v=sql.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: Yes I have 2012 version but I'm not understand how should I use it for filter of the last 24 hours.

Comment: In addition when I'm using the above code I'm getting the next error "Divide by zero error encountered." -- found the issue and resolve it.

Comment: There is no division in my sample. Can you edit your question to include the full SQL so we can hunt for the *divide by* error.

Comment: I fond what was the issue and solved it. I still not find a solution how to filter on last day results from 08:00 - 08:00 (of today).

Answer (score -1):

Use Date() ([How to part DATE and TIME from DATETIME in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337195/how-to-part-date-and-time-from-datetime-in-mysql)).

```
( DateDiff(HH, vw_public_task.complete_date, Date(getdate())+8 ) < 25)
```

Comment: How the +8 is helping me?

Comment: We strip the time element, and then add 8 hours to indicate 8 AM.