# Save the date time to database and query the hours only

Tags: php, mysql, date

I need you help. I have a Database then the database i have a date time to save it. this is the format

> date("d M Y H:i:s");

and this is the output when i query from the database.

> 30 Jun 2017 03:33:52

My problem is, i want to query only hours only without date how do i do that? somebody help me? thank you.

> 03:33:52

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to part DATE and TIME from DATETIME in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337195/how-to-part-date-and-time-from-datetime-in-mysql)

Comment: @FrankerZ i following the duplicate and my problem is not solve. this is my sql query what is the problem? $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(timer_date,'%H:%i:%s') TIMEONLY FROM timer");
            $query->execute();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways to solve this.

1st from your query, use:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT time(datetimecol) as thetime FROM timer"); 
$query->execute();
```

you get exact thetime is `time`

2nd, use full format datetime and convert it to time only in php

```
$return = 30 Jun 2017 03:33:52
$return = date("H:i:s", strtotime($return)); // 03:33:52
```

Comment: Thank you. i will try your solution .. i will feedback immediately

Comment: Sir tried your 1st solution, there is an output but, only day the out put. in my database store like this 29 Jun 2017 03:33:52 the output is like this 00:00:29 when i change the day in my database 30 Jun 2017 03:33:52 the output is 00:00:30

Comment: Make sure datetimecol is column name of your stored column (maybe timer_date?)

Comment: OMG! it work.. thank you sir. i use your second solution <?php 
      $return = $timer_query['timer_date'];
      $return = date("H:i:s", strtotime($return));
                 
      echo $return; ?>

Answer (score 1):

You don't want the hours, you want the time.  And MySQL has a convenient function for that:

```
select time(datetimecol)
```

If you want to format the column as a string, then you would just do:

```
select date_format(datetimecol, '%H:%i%s')
```