# Best Way to Store Time in Format HH:MM in MySQL for Performance

Tags: mysql, time

I am storing departure and arrival times as minutes(int) in database.

```
id, transport_date, departure_time, arrival_time
'3','2017-08-01',        '620',       '650'
```

and convert the minutes to time in JS:
e.g:

```
public String getDepartureTime() {
    return minuteToTime(departureTime);
}



public static String minuteToTime(int minute) {
  int hour = minute / 60;
  minute %= 60;
  String p = "AM";
  if (hour >= 12) {
    hour %= 12;
    p = "PM";
  }
  if (hour == 0) {
    hour = 12;
  }
  return (hour < 10 ? "0" + hour : hour) + ":" + (minute < 10 ? "0" + minute : minute) + " " + p;
}
```

and this returns `620` to `"10:20 AM"`. Is this a good approach to store time in database? or should I just change column datatype as varchar and save time as `10:20 AM`? Which way is faster, or has better performance?

Comment: Store date and time in one field as datetime

Comment: This link should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337195/how-to-part-date-and-time-from-datetime-in-mysql

Comment: In general, if I have a price I use `DECIMAL`, if I have a date I use `DATE` and if I have a time I use `TIME`. I need to have very specific use cases to stringify my data. Whatever, your overall design seems to assume that a transport can't last several days, make sure that underlying data complies with that.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález How you define TIME datatype in java class?

Comment: I don't know much Java but I suppose it could have a constructor that accepts strings and then parses and stores the values in whatever protected properties it needs (e.g. `hour`, `minutes` or `seconds_from_midnight`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing times in INT type or Varchar, you should use "datetime" data type for those columns and while retrieving we can extract time from these column with functions.

Ex :  Assuming that you have altered the datatypes to 'datetime' and your query will be

SELECT id, transport_date, Time(departure_time) As DepartureTime , Time(arrival_time) As ArrivalTime 
FROM Transport_TABLE;

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it,  is storing a column of type **DATETIME**, but concatenating a  fictitious date. E.g. *2018-01-01 13:05:00* (all years have a 1st January). 
Then when i want to get the time with a query I use the function [DATE_FORMAT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp)

E.g:

```
  `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MyColDateTime, '%H:%i:%s') TIME`
```

Or also when  I'm  working with php, i use:

```
    `$date = new DateTime('MyColDateTime');`
    `$time = $date->format('H:i:s');`
```

The way of store in **DATETIME** , is useful because it gives you the possibility, to use all the functions to work both in Mysql and in your programming language.