# Convert days,hours&minutes to a total of minutes

Tags: php, datetime

Sorry if this is not the correct place to post this but doing research on Google I haven't been able to find a suitable answer.

What I want to achieve is a user types in a date and time on the site and this gets inserted into the database (two different fields, a date field and a time field).

I then need to get the total of minutes until that day/time. I have the following code which prints out the days, hours and minutes. But I'm unsure of how to convert it to a total of minutes:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
$now = new DateTime();
$future_date = new DateTime(''.$Date.''.$Time.'');

$interval = $future_date->diff($now);

echo $interval->format("%a days, %h hours & %i minutes");
```

Comment: strtotime /60 I think would do it. What are date and time 2 fields, why not use `datetime`?

Comment: total minutes = days*24*60 + hours*60 + minutes

Comment: @user3783243 because I want to display the date and time separately and im not sure how to seperate with the DateTime format in MySQL. 

MadhurBhaiya; how do I get the days minutes and hours from the format() above?

Comment: For datetime seperation see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337195/how-to-part-date-and-time-from-datetime-in-mysql. You can just concat the two fields and use `strtotime` that will give you seconds, then divide by 60 to get minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$now = new DateTime();
$future_date = new DateTime($Date.' '.$Time);

$minutes = ($future_date->getTimestamp() - $now->getTimestamp())/60;
```

Unix timestamp stores the date in seconds. So you can calculate it without initialize a DateInterval with the diff() function.

Comment: That's worked, but I get the following: 2760.9166666667 


How do I round it to just the 2760 minutes?

Comment: If you always want to get to round down to integer number you should use floor(number); function. https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_math_floor.asp