# Date and hour issue on php

Tags: php, date, logic, hour

I have a report of machines that are inactive, the report is filtred by a date interval

Ex: from '2019-02-24' until '2019-02-26'

The user can set a 'shift' on the filter, Ex: shift A, shift B and shift C

The machines values come like this from the BD: Maq 01: stopped '2019-02-24 09:00:00' returned '2019-02-24 11:00:00'

Each shift has an specific schedule

> shift A : 05:00:00 until 13:30:00;
>
> shift B : 13:31:00 until  22:00:00;
>
> shift C : 22:01:00 until  04:59:00;

all values are transformed to srtotime

Assuming that the user select the interval between '2019-02-24' e '2019-02-26' and 'shift' A (05:00 until 13:30):

```
   values from BD: Machine 01
    stopped '2019-02-24 09:00:00', returned: '2019-02-24 10:00:00' = 1 hour stopped on 24/02 shift  A;
    stopped '2019-02-25 12:00:00', returned: '2019-02-25 15:00:00' = 1:30 hours stopped on 24/02 shift  A;
    I would like to create this parameter, the code identify that the shift chosen is shift A (05:00 ás 13:30), in all day selected, and then compile everything
ex: Mach 01 = hours stopped between 24/02 and 26 on shift A: 02:30:00
```

my code so far:

```
    $data_ida = '2019-02-24';
    data_volta '2019-02-26'
    $sql_ = "SELECT * FROM manutencao WHERE data BETWEEN '$data_ida' - interval 90 day AND '$data_volta' AND h_retorno != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ORDER BY id ASC";
            $disp_sql_ = $mysqli->query($sql_);
            $consulta  = $disp_sql_->num_rows;
            
            if($consulta > 0){
            while($data_2 = $disp_sql_->fetch_array())
            { 
                $h_stopped                = $data_2['h_parada'];
                $h_returned               = $data_2['h_retorno'];
                $num_mach                 = $data_2['num'];
                
                
                $day_begin       = strtotime($data_ida." 00:00:00");
                $day_end         = strtotime($data_volta." 23:59:00");
                $hour_begin_mach = strtotime($h_stopped);
                $hour_end_mach   = strtotime($h_retorned);
                
                    
            
                if($hour_begin_mach >= $day_begin && $hour_end_mach <= $day_end){
                        
                                       if($shift == 'a'){
                                            $shift_begin = '05:00:00';
                                            $shift_end   = '13:29:00';
                                        }elseif($shift == 'b'){
                                            $shift_begin = '13:30:00';
                                            $shift_end   = '22:00:00';
                                        }elseif($shift == 'c'){
                                            $shift_begin = '22:01:00';
                                            $shift_end   = '04:59:00';
                                        }
                    $strtotime_shift_begin =    strtotime($data_ida." ".$shift_begin);
                    $strtotime_shift_end   =    strtotime($data_volta." ".$shift_end);      
                    
                    
                    
                if($strtotime_shift_begin <= $hour_begin_mach && $strtotime_shift_end   >= $hour_end_mach ){
                                    
            
                        $diff      = $hour_end_mach - $hour_begin_mach ;
                        $stopped []= array('machine' => $num_mach, 'seconds' => $diff);
                        
                    }}
```

how can i do this code above, when the interval between dates is higher than 1 (ex. 24/02, 25/02 and 26/02)?

sorry for the bad english

Comment: You know, that you can extract time in MySQL by `DATE_FORMAT()` / `DATE()` / `TIME()`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12337231/1194525

Comment: Shifts don't have a start time and an end time, they have a start time and a _duration_. This change of perspective will greatly simplify your issue.