# How do you separate date and time from one column into two columns, with time format hh:mm?

Tags: sql

I want the date to show 04-23-2021 in one column and the for the second column to show time in a 18:56 format.

I already added the column where its supposed to go to.

I tried these two entries

```
UPDATE [dbo].[YearlyView]
SET [time_column] = FORMAT(CONVERT(datetime, [time_column]), 'HH:mm')


UPDATE [dbo].[YearlyView]
SET [time_column] = FORMAT(CONVERT(time, [time_column]), 'HH:mm')
```

This didnt work.

Comment: which specific sql are you using? This is for mysql
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337195/how-to-separate-date-and-time-from-datetime-in-mysql

Comment: ALTER TABLE [APR21]
ADD [Started_time] VARCHAR(5);

UPDATE [APR21]
SET [Started_time] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), [started_at], 108);

Comment: If the column is an actual `time` type, **there is no format**. The data is stored as non-human-readable **binary** value. You only format when you `SELECT` data out of the table. Date columns work the same if defined properly.

Comment: so you added the column [time_column] and you're trying to set [time_column] by formatting [time_column] which will be full of nulls since you just added it

Comment: Hi - why are you trying to split a single timestamp between two columns when you can just get the result you want when you query the data - or create a view if you don't want to write the SQL each time?

Comment: @NickW Hi, Im fairly new to the analysis row so Im trying to clean the data to show in their own columns for me to clean it nicely in tableau.

Comment: Then I would suggest creating a view over the table that does this for you - rather than physically creating additional columns, populating and maintaining them

Comment: @NickW Thank you for the feedback! I will look into creating views over tables